# Query data using LINQ to SQL and Entity Framework with foreign key?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, entity-framework

There is a problem I need help with your query on the data using LINQ to SQL and Entity Framework (I'm using Visual Studio 2010).

I have three tables:

1. `tblNewsDetails`
2. `tblNewsCategories`
3. `tblNewsInCategories`

(See photo 1 in the picture below.)

Now, I want to retrieve records in the `tblNewsDetails` table, with condition `CategoryId=1`, as shown in photo 2 in the picture below.

But `NewsID` and `CategoryId` in `tblNewsInCategories` table are two foreign keys. I do not see them and I do not know how to use them in my code.

Also, my code has errors, shown in photo 3 in the picture below.

http://img.tamtay.vn/files/photo2/2010/5/28/10/962/4bff3a3b_1093f58f_untitled-1.gif

Comment: I really doubt you're using LINQ to SQL *and* Entity Framework at the same time... You're probably using Linq to Entities, not Linq to SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple approaches possible, here's one of em

```
from n in tblNewsInCategories.Include("NewsCategory").Include("NewsDetail")
where n.NewsCategory.CategoryID == 1
select n.NewsDetail
```

remember that n (and b, in your exemple) are TblNewsInCategories entities, which probably have the following properties :

```
{
    public int NewsInCategories { get; set; } // your middle table primary key
    public TblNewsCategory NewsCategory { get; set; } // a navigation property
    public TblNewsDetails NewsDetail { get; set; } // a navigation property
}
```

so in order to access NewsId and CategoryId, you have to go through the navigation properties.

Comment: Thank you very much Dynami Le-Savard. I have solved this problem.
(I've lost three days to try to solve).
You're a good person, and have good knowledge.
I want to make friends with you on facebook :-)